# Extract highlighted words from Word to Excel

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, ms-word, vba

How can I extract highlighted words from Microsoft Word into an Excel template?

The template is already created. I want the text from the Word document to be put into the Excel document I already have.

```vb
'code that highlights word "olympics"

Dim sFindText As String

sFindText = "Olympics"

Selection.ClearFormatting
Selection.HomeKey wdStory, wdMove
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Execute sFindText

Do Until Selection.Find.Found = False
    Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    Selection.MoveRight
    Selection.Find.Execute
Loop
```

Comment: you have the code which highlights words and these highlighted words you want to extract to excel in the same step or as a next step? show your code anyway...

Comment: please, add it to your question by re-edition of it.

Comment: by the way, you should remove the other question of your as long as it's duplicate of this one.

Comment: next question- what do you mean by extracting to excel- where? to new empty workbook? one below the other? etc. add the answer to your question to make it complex.

Comment: You can get the value/word from `Selection.Range.Text`

Comment: can you elaborate? I want the highlighted word "olympics" to now be pulled from the word document and placed in an excel table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after you run your code you need to run the one below to transfer all highlighted words to your excel file.  See additional comments within proposed solution.

```
Selection.ClearFormatting
Selection.HomeKey wdStory, wdMove
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

'here you set searching for highlighted words
Selection.Find.Highlight = True
Selection.Find.Execute

'lets open your workbook within new Excel application
    Dim EXL As Object
    Set EXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Dim xlsWB As Object 'which will be a workbook

    Dim xlsPath As String
    'put path to your file here
    xlsPath = "c:\Temp Priv\TestFile.xlsm"

    Set xlsWB = EXL.workbooks.Open(xlsPath)

    Dim xlsRow As Long

Do Until Selection.Find.Found = False

        'we will write found words to first sheet in your Workbook,  _
         consecutive rows in column A

        xlsRow = xlsRow + 1
        xlsWB.sheets(1).Cells(xlsRow, "A") = Selection.Text
        Selection.Find.Execute

Loop
'lets show our excel application
    EXL.Visible = True
```

Comment: the solution provided works perfectly for simple excel workbook. if your file is read-only then make it read-write.

Comment: How can I manipulate this code to insert the text elsewhere. Say, B2, or A3